# Sql query to select records only when count(column)=1

Tags: sql, oracle10g, case

I am trying to retrieve records from oracle 10g express.

I want to execute :

```
select name|| '=' || id from literals where name='vge_1'
```

only when count(vge_1) is equal to 1.

else I want to display an error.

I tried following query, but its giving

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

THe query I tried is as follows:

```
select case(name) 
when count('vge_1') then (select name|| '=' || id from literals where name='vge_1';)
else Errror 
end
from Literals where name='vge_1';
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `count()` takes a column name or expression. Are you saying `vge_1` is a column name? Or are you trying to return a value only when there is one row with `vge_1` in the `name` column of your table?

Comment: I am trying to return a value only when there is one 'vge_1' value in the name column of my table

Comment: @dwurf also, there might be more then 1 records in table. So I cant use distinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe716/33):

```
select distinct case 
    when l2.c = 1 then l1.name || '=' || l1.id
    else 'Error'
end as name_id
from literals l1,
(
    select name, count(name) as c
    from literals
    where name = 'vge_1'
    group by name
    having count(name) = 1
) l2
where l1.name = l2.name(+)
and l1.name = 'vge_1'
;
```

The inner query is roughly same as the other answers. The outer query uses a left outer join `(+)` to determine if the inner query contains a match for your `count()` restriction.

Note that you must update the name in two places when running this query.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `case` add `HAVING count(name)=1` in the end of th query

Comment: this query works as I want. But I also to print an error message if count is more then 1. I think I cant do it using Having clause. Any other option??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select b.id,a.* from
(select name from Literals 
where name='vge_1'
group by name
having count(name)=1)a,Literals b
where b.name=a.name
```

Comment: this query works as I want. But I also to print an error message if count is more then 1. I think I cant do it using Having clause. Any other option??